# problem with operator+ priority in making a HyperComplex class

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading, overloading

I'm making a HyperComplex class just for practice, I have problem with operator+ behaviour between 2 HyperComplex variables, I get the regular complex operator+,
I tried also to do 2 opeartor+ (1 with Hc and Complex, second with complex and Hc, but that gave me ambigious eroor)

here's my code:

```
class Complex {
public:
 Complex(const T& real = 0, const T& imaginary = 0);
 Complex(const Complex&) = default;
 virtual ~Complex() {};
 Complex& operator=(const Complex&) = default;
 Complex& operator+=(const Complex&);
 }
protected:
 T real;
 T imaginary;
};

template <class T>
Complex<T>& Complex<T>::operator+=(const Complex<T>& rhs){
    real += rhs.real;
    imaginary += rhs.imaginary;
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
Complex<T> operator+(const Complex<T>& lhs, const Complex<T>& rhs){
    Complex<T> tmp = lhs;
    return tmp += rhs; 
}

template <class T>
class HyperComplex: public Complex<T> {
    private:
    T j_part;
    public :
    HyperComplex(const T& real = 0, const T& imaginary = 0, const T& j_part = 0): Complex<T>(real,imaginary), j_part(j_part) {}    
    HyperComplex(const HyperComplex&) = default;                                      
    HyperComplex(const Complex<T>& p): Complex<T>(p) , j_part(0) {
        const HyperComplex* ptr = dynamic_cast<const HyperComplex*>(&p);
        if (ptr != nullptr){
            j_part = ptr->j_part;
        }
    }    // copy ctor gets ref to complex
    HyperComplex<T>& operator+=(const HyperComplex<T>& rhs){
        this->real += rhs.real;
        this->imaginary += rhs.imaginary;
        j_part += rhs.j_part;
        return *this;
    }

};

template <class T>
HyperComplex<T> operator+(const HyperComplex<T>& lhs, const Complex<T>& rhs){
    HyperComplex<T> tmp = lhs;
    return tmp += rhs; 
}

template <class T>
HyperComplex<T> operator+(const Complex<T>& lhs, const HyperComplex<T>& rhs){
    HyperComplex<T> tmp = rhs;
    return tmp += lhs; 
}
```

when I run this code :

```
   HyperComplex<int> hc(4,2,4) ;
    HyperComplex<int> hc1 = hc + hc;
    HyperComplex<int> hc2 = c2;
    HyperComplex<int> hc3 = hc + c2;
    HyperComplex<int> hc4 = c2 + hc;
```

I get ambigous in hc1 calc

Comment: That's too much code.  Make a minimal example by removing everything that isn't directly related to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the destructor of the class template Complex shall be virtual

```
virtual ~Complex() = default;
```

Make this constructor

```
HyperComplex(const Complex<T>& p);
```

explicit

```
explicit HyperComplex(const Complex<T>& p);
```

Otherwise an object of the type `Complex` can be implicitly converted to an object of the type `HyperComplex` and vice versa.

As a result either the operator

```
template <class T>
Complex<T> operator+(const Complex<T>& lhs, const Complex<T>& rhs){
    Complex<T> tmp = lhs;
    return tmp += rhs; 
}
```

or the operator

```
template <class T>
HyperComplex<T> operator+(const HyperComplex<T>& lhs, const HyperComplex<T>& rhs){
    HyperComplex<T> tmp = lhs;
    return tmp += rhs; 
}
```

can be called in these statements

```
HyperComplex<int> hc3 = hc + c2;
HyperComplex<int> hc4 = c2 + hc;
```

Another approach is to declare explicitly two more operators like

```
template <class T>
HyperComplex<T> operator+(const HyperComplex<T>& lhs, const Complex<T>& rhs);
```

and

```
template <class T>
HyperComplex<T> operator+(const Complex<T>& lhs, const HyperComplex<T>& rhs);
```

But in any case the constructors of the classes with default arguments should be declared as explicit.

Comment: hi, but that's not my meaning. I want this line of code to work :```HyperComplex<int> hc2 = c2;```

Comment: @Tuxedo You can write instead HyperComplex<int> hc2( c2 );

Comment: I am looking for a way for this to work naturally without castings, but thanks

Comment: @Tuxedo  Vlad from Moscow also said you can provide another 2 overloads `Complex<T> + HyperComplex<T>` and `HyperComplex<T> + Complex<T>`. this is the cost if you want that implicit casting.

Comment: Did that and got Ambigious error from compiler

Comment: @Tuxedo The ambiguity between which operator overloading?

Comment: in ```HyperComplex<int> hc1 = hc + hc;``` I get ambigious between the three operator+ available ( Complex<T> + HC<T> , HC<T> + C<T>, and C<T> + C<T>

Comment: @Tuxedo Firstly make the destructor of the class template Complex virtual. And I cannot reproduce the error. In the list of ambiguous operators there is no operator HC<T> + HC<T>. Did you forget to define it?

Comment: I chnged in your advice from hc + hc to (c+hc and hc +c ) , i really forgot the virtual dtor, also edited my question with the edited code

Comment: @Tuxedo One more you forgot to declare the operator HC + HC.

Comment: thank you so much. could you explain why the compiler prefer the c + hc or hc + c (calling a conversion from c to hc for template function) above using hc as ref to c and calling c + c ?

Comment: @Tuxedo The compiler selects the best suitable overloaded operator that does not require conversions of its arguments.

Comment: thank you vlad! I'm new to this site, tell me if there's a `thank you` button

Answer (score 0):

the problem was fixed! solution is 4 different operator+ :

```
Complex<T> operator+(const Complex<T>& lhs, const Complex<T>& rhs){
    Complex<T> tmp = lhs;
    return tmp += rhs; 
}

template <class T>
HyperComplex<T> operator+(const HyperComplex<T>& lhs, const Complex<T>& rhs){
    HyperComplex<T> tmp = lhs;
    return tmp += rhs; 
}

template <class T>
HyperComplex<T> operator+(const Complex<T>& lhs, const HyperComplex<T>& rhs){
    HyperComplex<T> tmp = rhs;
    return tmp += lhs; 
}

template <class T>
HyperComplex<T> operator+(const HyperComplex<T>& lhs, const HyperComplex<T>& rhs){
    HyperComplex<T> tmp = rhs;
    return tmp += lhs; 
}
```